# Creating a custom definition/property for a control

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently about to design a project that uses a `DataGridView`. As one of the events I would like it to perform a task upon double-clicking on a row.

Looking around I can find examples of creating your own event, however I notice that `DataGridView` has no property or definition for double-clicking a row, and was wondering how I could specify this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [`CellMouseDoubleClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmousedoubleclick.aspx) event that, in contrast to the "normal" DataGridView's mouse double click event, fires only when the user actually double-clicks the cell of a row.

---

About the question on how to do it yourself: You could try to derive a new class from `DataGridView`, attach the `CellMouseDoubleClick` event internally and just fire a new event, passing the clicked row. For example:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) 
{
    // Determine the row the clicked cell belongs to
    ...

    // Fire a new event for that row
    ...
}
```

Comment: Valid answer, although it would be interesting if there is a way to specify custom properties? I could run it with that but from a learning point of view it would be handy if there is a way to do it :)

Comment: @RyanHargreaves I added to my answer about how to add a new event *could* be implemented.